# How to deploy to Heroku directly from my Gitlab repository

Tags: git, heroku, deployment, gitlab, continuous-deployment

In my team, we use Gitlab as a remote repository, so we are looking for a solution to auto deploy our apps to Heroku. We found Codeship for auto deploying apps to Heroku from Github.

Any tips? Tricks?

Comment: http://doc.gitlab.com/ce/ci/deployment/README.html

Comment: I already read this. In documentation, we will setup a GitLab Runner. It likes Travis CI.

Comment: @karmiphuc 404 ...

Comment: @CharlieSchliesser https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/

Answer (score 54):

If you are not prepared to use Ruby/dpl you can deploy to Heroku as follows:

Look up your Heroku API key (Account settings -> API Key on the Heroku web console) and make it available as a Gitlab secret variable e.g. HEROKU_API_KEY  (Please note the values is not the same as what heroku auth:token returns...)

Then add two script lines in your `.gitlab-ci.yml` config file at the relevant job:

```
git remote add heroku https://heroku:$HEROKU_API_KEY@git.heroku.com/<name of your heroku app>.git

git push -f heroku HEAD:master
```

You can see detailed explanation at http://blog.thecodewhisperer.com/permalink/deploying-jekyll-to-heroku-using-gitlab-ci

Comment: Make sure to add `-q` flag while pushing to heroku otherwise you'll reveal your `$HEROKU_API_KEY` at the end of your output.

Comment: @Zsolt When I do that, the push is empty (the heroku build therefore fail), what I am missing here ? Do I need to make a dummy commit to init `heroku:master` ?

Comment: running `git remote add heroku ...` in .gitlab-ci.yml sometimes causes `fatal: remote heroku already exists`
changed it to `git remote add heroku ... || true` to force return code to 0

Answer (score 33):

[Here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/examples/test-and-deploy-python-application-to-heroku.html#configure-project) is the solution I found , restating in case the link is broken:

**Configure project**

This is what the .gitlab-ci.yml file looks like for this project:

```
test:
  script:
  # this configures Django application to use attached postgres database that is run on `postgres` host
  - export DATABASE_URL=postgres://postgres:@postgres:5432/python-test-app
  - apt-get update -qy
  - apt-get install -y python-dev python-pip
  - pip install -r requirements.txt
  - python manage.py test

staging:
  type: deploy
  script:
  - apt-get update -qy
  - apt-get install -y ruby-dev
  - gem install dpl
  - dpl --provider=heroku --app=gitlab-ci-python-test-staging --api-key=$HEROKU_STAGING_API_KEY
  only:
  - master

production:
  type: deploy
  script:
  - apt-get update -qy
  - apt-get install -y ruby-dev
  - gem install dpl
  - dpl --provider=heroku --app=gitlab-ci-python-test-prod --api-key=$HEROKU_PRODUCTION_API_KEY
  only:
  - tags
```

This project has three jobs:

> test - used to test Django application,
>
> staging - used to automatically deploy staging environment every push to master branch
>
> production - used to automatically deploy production environmnet for every created tag

**Store API keys**

You'll need to create two variables in Project > Variables:

```
HEROKU_STAGING_API_KEY - Heroku API key used to deploy staging app,
HEROKU_PRODUCTION_API_KEY - Heroku API key used to deploy production app.
```

Comment: Hi dnit13, where exactly is that path ```Project > Variables``` ? Im not finding it in Gitlab

Comment: @CynthiaSanchez As described by Zsolt below, you will find the api key in your heroku account

Comment: It's at  `Settings > CI/CD > Environment variables`

Answer (score 0):

To complete dnit13's answer:

**Make sure your environment variables are unprotected.**

Go to `Settings > CI/CD > Environment variables` and untick `Protected Variable`.

More information on [this thread](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/issues/43209).

Comment: This is not really a good idea. Some variables should be kept secret. A better answer would have been: "Make sure to only use protected variables on protected branches."

Answer (score 0):

base on the documentaion of gitlab-ci has deployment tool that use to directly communicate with these providers, Heroku, Cloud Foundry, AWS/S3 etc.

here is the basic usage of `dpl` for your `job` script

```yaml
staging:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - apt-get update -yq
    - apt-get install -y ruby-dev
    - gem install dpl
    - dpl --provider=heroku --app=my-app-staging --api_key=$HEROKU_STAGING_API_KEY
  only:
    - main
```

for those seeker here just read this [gitlab dpl documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/examples/deployment/)