# Automatic deploy from gitlab to heroku

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, gitlab

Hi guys i was wondering if it is possible to make automatic deploys from gitlab to heroku (react app), right now this is my gitlab-ci

```
image: node:8.10.0-alpine
cache:
  key: "alpine"
  paths:
    - node_modules/

before_script:
  - npm install

build:
  stage: build
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - dist/
  script:
    - npm run build
  only:
    - master
  tags:
    - docker
```

is there a way to push the builded proyect to heroku?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to deploy to Heroku directly from my Gitlab repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37048511/how-to-deploy-to-heroku-directly-from-my-gitlab-repository)

Comment: i saw that post it got me confused im not sure if that applys for my react project, also if i just push to heroku wouldnt i be pushing my master insted of my dist?

Comment: You'd have to change the build process since it's Python-specific, but the rest (everything the question asks about) looks like it applies.

Comment: im really new to this and i kind of get lost with that post can you help me out?

Comment: I think you are looking for this: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/examples/test-and-deploy-python-application-to-heroku.html

Comment: @NicolasAlbarracin, what part of it is unclear?

Comment: The example is made for phyton im not sure how to translated for node